# On the mechanics of audio acquisition; Android, Java

Tags: java, android, audio, buffer, acquisition

I am acquiring an audio signal at 44.1k using the following code and need to understand the mechanics better.  Just for reference, all the code works.

I am defining a block of 1024 that is being pulled from AudioRecord.read and being placed into a buffer.  Then I do a hanning window and an FT (jfftpack), then use this data elsewhere (publishProgress).

Since my buffer is only 1024, and the min audio buffer is 4096, what happens to the remaining ~3000?

Does the *.read(buffer...) command read sequencially, ie 0-1024 on first use, 1025-2048 on second, etc.?

Basically I am wondering now how much information I am losing.

THanks for the help!

Below is code:------------
(It is modified versions of the jfft utilization in a frequency analyzer coupled with a hanning window, and then it uses a buffered writer to write all the data points to a log file.)

```
package com.example.frequencytest;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import jfftpack.javasource.ca.uol.aig.fftpack.RealDoubleFFT;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    int frequency = 44100;
    int channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
    int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
    private RealDoubleFFT transformer;
    int blockSize = 1024;
    public double movingAvg = 0.0;
    public int movingAvgCnt = 0;
    public BufferedWriter buf = null;
    File tempFile = new File("sdcard/Data_Log.txt");

    Button startStopButton;
    boolean started = false;

    RecordAudio recordTask;
    TextView textView1;

    ImageView imageView;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    Canvas canvas;
    Paint paint;

    //AudioRecord audioRecord;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startStopButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.StartStopButton);
        startStopButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        transformer = new RealDoubleFFT(blockSize);

        imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) 1024, (int) 300,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }

    public class RecordAudio extends AsyncTask<Void, double[], Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            try {
                int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(frequency, 
                        channelConfiguration, audioEncoding); 
                AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord( 
                        MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, frequency, 
                        channelConfiguration, audioEncoding, bufferSize); 

                short[] buffer = new short[blockSize];
                double[] toTransform = new double[blockSize];
                audioRecord.startRecording();

                // started = true; hopes this should true before calling
                // following while loop

                while (started) {
                    int bufferReadResult = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0,
                            blockSize);

                    for (int i = 0; i < blockSize && i < bufferReadResult; i++) {
                        toTransform[i] = (double) buffer[i] / 32768.0;
                    }
                        toTransform = HanningWindow(toTransform,0,blockSize);
                        transformer.ft(toTransform);
                        publishProgress(toTransform);
                }

                audioRecord.stop();
                buf.close();

            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("AudioRecord", "Recording Failed");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(double[]... toTransform) {

            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

            double average = 0.0;
            int averageCnt=1;
            for (int i = 0; i < toTransform[0].length; i++) {
                int x = i;
                int downy = (int) (100 - (toTransform[0][i] * 10));
                int upy = 100;

                if(i>2 && i<(toTransform[0].length/2)){
                    average += Math.sqrt(Math.abs(toTransform[0][i]));
                    averageCnt++;
                }
                canvas.drawLine(x, downy, x, upy, paint);              
            }
            average = average/averageCnt;
            movingAvg += average;
            movingAvgCnt++;
            if(movingAvgCnt==5){
                movingAvg = movingAvg/movingAvgCnt;

                textView1.setText(""+movingAvg);
                try{
                      buf.append("" + average + ","+movingAvg);
                      buf.newLine();
                   }catch (IOException e)
                       {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                       }
                movingAvg = 0.0;
                movingAvgCnt = 0;
            }   
            imageView.invalidate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (started) {
            started = false;
            startStopButton.setText("Start");
            recordTask.cancel(true);
        } else {
            started = true;
            startStopButton.setText("Stop");
            setupTempFile();
            recordTask = new RecordAudio();
            recordTask.execute();
        }
    }

    public void setupTempFile(){
        Log.d("Process", "startRecording");

        if (tempFile.exists()){tempFile.delete();}
        if (!tempFile.exists())
           {
              try
              {
                 tempFile.createNewFile();
              } 
              catch (IOException e)
              {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }
              try
               {
                  //BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file flag
                  buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile, true)); 
                  buf.append("Data Val, Moving Average");
                  buf.newLine();
               }
               catch (IOException e)
               {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e.printStackTrace();
               }

           }
    }
    public short[] HanningWindow(short[] signal_in, int pos, int size)
    {
        for (int i = pos; i < pos + size; i++)
        {
            int j = i - pos; // j = index into Hann window function
            signal_in[i] = (short) (signal_in[i] * 0.5 * (1.0 - Math.cos(2.0 * Math.PI * j / size)));
        }
        return signal_in;
    }

    public double[] HanningWindow(double[] signal_in, int pos, int size)
    {
        for (int i = pos; i < pos + size; i++)
        {
            int j = i - pos; // j = index into Hann window function
            signal_in[i] = (double) (signal_in[i] * 0.5 * (1.0 - Math.cos(2.0 * Math.PI * j / size)));
        }
        return signal_in;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it works similarly to socket reads, then you should be getting the full 0 to 1023 the first time, 1024 to 2047 the second, etc.

That being said - I am observing a bit of somewhat related strangeness myself.  I have placed timing code around the read.  I have minBuffer of 256 and buffer size of 256 running at 44.1KHz.  It seems that sometimes the read function takes 0 time...  Yet still returns 256 bytes worth of goodness.

```
01-10 23:37:07.230: E/(15224): EllapsedTime 9 and readResult is 256
01-10 23:37:07.240: E/(15224): EllapsedTime 0 and readResult is 256
01-10 23:37:07.240: E/(15224): EllapsedTime 8 and readResult is 256
01-10 23:37:07.250: E/(15224): EllapsedTime 9 and readResult is 256
01-10 23:37:07.260: E/(15224): EllapsedTime 1 and readResult is 256
01-10 23:37:07.260: E/(15224): EllapsedTime 8 and readResult is 256
01-10 23:37:07.260: E/(15224): EllapsedTime 1 and readResult is 256
```

01-10 23:37:07.270: E/WTF(15224): EllapsedTime 9 and readResult is 256
01-10 23:37:07.280: E/WTF(15224): EllapsedTime 0 and readResult is 256